# Difference between NOT EXISTS and COUNT(*)

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting a different response between two statements that I would consider to be equivalent: `SELECT COUNT(*)` vs `NOT EXISTS`. In ~49 out 50 executions these two statements behave the same, but occasionally they do not.

My guess is there is a difference between how these statements handle locked pages or something maybe something more 'far out'. My question is what is that difference?

I originally added some logging (STATEMENT 3) to my SPROC which is how I saw they had different values. Since the contents of `TableWithResults` can change while this SPROC is executing, is I added STATEMENT #3 so I could confirm the result of `COUNT(*)` before and after the `NOT EXISTS`:

```
-- STATEMENT 1: If this is returning 1...
SET @MatchingResultCount1 = ( SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TableWithResults  WHERE  SearchId = @SearchId ) 

-- STATEMENT 2: ...I expect this to evaluate "False" and sets IS_VALID='Y'
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM TableWithResults WHERE  SearchId = @SearchId )
   SET @IS_VALID = 'N';
ELSE
   SET @IS_VALID = 'Y';

-- STATEMENT 3: This is to confirm the table didn't change
SET @MatchingResultCount1 = ( SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TableWithResults  WHERE  SearchId = @SearchId )
```

What I'm seeing is `@MatchingResultCount1` and `@MatchingResultCount2` are 100% always the same. *Almost* all the time `@IS_VALID = 'Y'` when `@MatchingResultCount1 > 0`, but 1/50 times, `@IS_VALID = 'N'` when `@MatchingResultCount1 > 0`.

I tried using `WITH (NOLOCK)` on all statements and that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: where is Not Exists?  the one in if condition?  if so how this question in count(*) vs not exists?

Comment: do you have index on SearchId? maybe when using count, SQL server uses data in the table but when you use exists, it uses index and your index may be corrupted. This might be nonsense but that just a thought.

Comment: I don't see your explained logic or `@MatchingResultCount2` implemented in your script and it appears your test is unrepeatable. Maybe your matching row gets deleted in between

Comment: @MohammadSanati You know, this wouldn't be the first time a corrupt index was the last thing I thought of. I'll rebuild it this weekend and see what happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You should usually prefer `NOT EXISTS` over `COUNT(*)` for a very simple reason:

When you say `COUNT(*)`, the database doesn't know that you don't really care about the *exact* number of rows. So, it cannot skip the remaining results as soon as *at least* one row matching the `WHERE` clause has been found.

Now, as a side-effect, this may also result in a `COUNT(*)` query acquiring more locks than a `NOT EXISTS` query in case `NOT EXISTS` manages to skip rows. This will depend on the database (I'm not sure about SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your logic quite a bit here.

```
DECLARE @IS_VALID char(1) = 'N'

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM TableWithResults WHERE  SearchId = @SearchId )
   SET @IS_VALID = 'Y';
```

I don't understand your bit about locked pages here. The returned value will always be the same at the moment you run your query. It is possible you can get different results at different moments during execution if there are other transactions locking pages in this table.

Answer (score -2):

Insert and update in one condition in `SQL`

```
declare @countvariable int
set @countvariable = (select count(*) from tablename where columname = @parametername)

if(@countvariable =0)
begin
    insert condition
end
else
begin
    update condition
end
```