# Find the sailors that have been on EVERY boat

Tags: sql, group-by, count, distinct

I don't know how to explain the problem in a generic way so i'll post the specific case:

i have 3 tables:

Sailors:

```
S(ids, names, rating, age)
```

Boats:

```
B(idb, nameb, color)
```

Bookings:

```
Bo(ids, idb, date)
```

i have to write a query that finds all the sailors who have booked EVERY boat.

Even if i posted a specific case i'd like a generic answare that can be applied to every problem of tha same kind.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Find sailors for which there isn't a boat for which there isn't a booking record for that sailor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the sailors's ids who have booked every boat with this query:

```
select ids
from bookings
group by ids
having count(distinct idb) = (select count(*) from boats)
```

So use it either with the operator `IN`:

```
select * from sailors
where ids in (
    select ids
    from bookings
    group by ids
    having count(distinct idb) = (select count(*) from boats)
)
```

or join it to `sailors`:

```
select s.*
from sailors s 
inner join (
    select ids
    from bookings
    group by ids
    having count(distinct idb) = (select count(*) from boats)
) t on t.ids = s.ids
```

Comment: This should work very well on test data, but should be much slower than a `not exists` on real data.

Comment: GSerg can you be more specific?

Comment: @GSerg can you post a solution with NOT EXISTS?

Comment: @GuglielmoLaMastra https://stackoverflow.com/a/35212957/11683, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5264658/11683, many others.

Comment: @GSerg I mean solution applicable to this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum` with `in`:

```
select * from sailors s1 group by ids having (select sum(idb in (select b2.idb from bookings b2 where b2.ids = s1.id)) from boats) = (select count(*) from boats)
```